# How to Save an Append or Delete Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I'm moving from MS Access to MySQL:

In MS Access you can store certain INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE queries as objects alongside your tables. Thus for anyone who don't understand computers that well, they can click on the objects and automatically run the queries to alter the master table for various business functions.

In MySQL, where and how do you store these queries, I seem to be only able to make tables. When I write a piece of code using the SQL editor, I can only save it to a remote location (such as my local desktop) and not onto the MySQL database, where it's accessible for my coworkers.

If you can't save it onto the server, how would I write a piece of code and execute it within the database that would be easily usable by others.

Thanks

Comment: Something like a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is going to depend on your environment, your users, and your bandwidth to support any given solution. You are gaining a lot by making the switch from Access to MySQL, however you are losing some of the the WYSIWYG features. (e.g., Access forms that can bind directly to your data source.)

There are many approaches:

1. If your users are more advanced, simply having access to the database using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) may suffice. From there they would have access to run views, stored procedures, or to create their own custom queries.
2. Another option would be to script your objects using Python and provide a simple gui using [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). Python is generally thought of as an easy to use language; with built in suppport for MySQL and TkInter is its "default" interface.
3. Using the LAMP architecture is another largely popular paradigm using MySQL as the backend database.
4. There is also nothing stopping you from [using Access to link to your MySQL db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) using MySQL as an external data source.

I hope this provides enough info to help you begin whittling down your options.